# jQuery - How to make clickable a var text placed in another var composed by more elements (var, checkbox)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I've made a var element (artwork_html) to append in a div (append_div):

This element is formed by:
a checkbox with a value + class and a Name that contains text (text that comes from an array and is been modified replacing some parts of it).

```
var name;
var artwork_html = "";
name = value['artwork']['value'].replace("http://dbpedia.org/resource/", "");

artwork_html += "<div><b>" +'<input class=artworks_checkbox type=checkbox value='+ value['artwork']['value'] + '/>' + " " + name + "</b></div>";

$('#append_div').append(artwork_html);
```

That creates a checkbox and a text (the var name) like this:

```
 [] Primavera_(Botticelli)
 [] Nascita_di_Venere_(Botticelli)
 [] Bacco_(Caravaggio)
```

How can i click on the name firing a simple event

```
 alert("Name Clicked!");
```

thanks in advance

***UPDATE***

Both the replies of Ankit Saroch and Subhasom work.
Thanks!

Comment: so u want to get id of the clicked checkbox?

Comment: no, i want just to click on the name (not the checkbox) and fire an event... the checkbox makes other things in this script.

Comment: put checkbox in label tag and giv different classes, on click check the class and set checkbox checked

Comment: i've tried to give the var name a class but it doesn't work. Have i to give the label to the whole composed var or only to the single var?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have the name inside a `label` tag. And then bind a click event on that label.

So, your div string would be like below:

```
artwork_html += "<div><b>" +'<input class=artworks_checkbox type=checkbox value='+ value['artwork']['value'] + '/>' + " <label class='artworkName'>" + name + "</label></b></div>";
```

Bind the click event with `on` on the append_div element like below:

```
$('#append_div').on('click', '.artworkName', function(){
   alert($(this).html());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the old line:

```
artwork_html += "<div><b>" +'<input class=artworks_checkbox type=checkbox value='+ value['artwork']['value'] + '/>' + " " + name + "</b></div>";
```

with the new line as follow:

```
artwork_html += "<div><b>" +'<input class=artworks_checkbox type=checkbox value='+ value['artwork']['value'] + '/>' + " <span onclick='alert(this.innerHTML)'>" + name + "</span></b></div>";
```

This simply creates like before as bellow but when you click non the name it triggers `alert(Name)`